# How can I create a compressed tar in sun solaris?

Tags: tar

I am logged into Sun Solaris OS. I want to create and extract a compressed tar file. I tried this normal UNIX command:

```
tar -cvzf file.tar.gz directory1
```

It is failing to execute in Sun OS with following error

```
bash-3.2$ tar -cvzf file.tar.tz directory1
tar: z: unknown function modifier
Usage: tar {c|r|t|u|x}[BDeEFhilmnopPqTvw@[0-7]][bfk][X...] [blocksize] [tarfile] [size] [exclude-file...] {file | -I include-file | -C directory file}...
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a normal UNIX command?

Comment: I think you need to spend some time reading on the differences between Unixes Linux and GNU tools.

Comment: When they added that `z` flag to GNU tar, we lost our greatest example for teaching people how to think logically and construct a pipeline...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To avoid creation of temporary intermediate file you can use this command

```
tar cvf - directory1|gzip -c >file.tar.gz
```

Comment: This has the potential advantage that some of the processing can happen in parallel.

Comment: Is the `f -` needed, or does Solaris `tar` output to stdout by default?

Comment: @Mark: According to the [man page](http://ibgwww.colorado.edu/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/solaris/tar.1.html), "If `f` is omitted, `tar` will use the device indicated by the `TAPE` environment variable, if set; otherwise, it will use the default values defined in `/etc/default/tar`." So, no, it doesn't look like you can safely assume that `f -` isn't needed.

Comment: @Romeo: Thanks for the answer, I found it useful. Can you clarify why "-" is needed between cvf and directory name?
Additionally, I tried your command on several OSs - Solaris 10, 11.4, Linux (RHEL, CentOS, Oracle, etc.) and works consistently. I also reviewed the respective tar man pages - why does the above work in Linux without "-" before the cvf ? I would expect Linux to require something like "tar -cvf ...."
Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: @rc1, the dash in tar mean you set the output file to be STDOUT. There are two styles of parameters, BSD and SYSV. And Linux tar work with both of them (with and w/o dash before cvf)

Answer (score 10):

[Looks like](http://ibgwww.colorado.edu/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/solaris/tar.1.html) Solaris's `tar` doesn't know how to compress. So just do it manually:

```
tar -cvf file.tar directory1 && gzip file.tar
```

That's all the `-z` switch of GNU tar does, anyway. The command above will produce `file.tar.gz`.

Comment: This will work (as long as you have enough spare disk space to store the intermediate uncompressed `file.tar` archive), but it's needlessly slow and wasteful of disk space. I can't think of any situation where this would be preferable to [Romeo Ninov's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361906).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen neither can I. I just thought of this first.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have`SUNWgtar` installed. This is the GNU version of `tar` and provides `/usr/sfw/bin/gtar` which will allow the use of the GNU options to tar.

Answer (score -2):

Please try below command

```
tar -cvf file.tar directory1 && gzip file.tar
```

(to zip the file on solaris)

```
gunzip file.tar.gz
```

(to unzip)

Comment: This doesn’t add a whole bunch beyond [a previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361901/117549)

Comment: It also just dumps the whole tar file (including all the binary in the headers) onto the terminal, instead of unarchiving the files. You would probably need to reset the terminal afterwards.